# Spring @RequestBody not mapping to custom Object

Tags: json, spring, spring-restcontroller

I have this custom Object called Example, that have a org.json.JSONObject as a mongo query.

```
public class ExampleObject {

private JSONObject query;
private String[] projections;
private Number limit;

// Constructors, getters and setters

}
```

I'm using a REST controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleRestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String example(@RequestBody ExampleObject example) {

    return "This is an example";
}
```

And then, I do with Postman the following request:

> POST to http://localhost:8080/example/search

with body as follows (I have checked the validity of the JSON with http://jsonlint.com):

```
{
"query":{
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2"
    },
"projections":["field3, field4"],
"limit":3
}
```

The result is: projections and limit on object "example" have setted correctly but query is an empty JSONObject (not null). If I don't send the field query, the JSONObject variable on the object "example" is null.

I don't understand why the field query is not setted fine. I want to Spring maps the @RequestBody json to an ExampleObject.

Comment: I am suspecting of Jackson not knowing how to deserialize `JSONObject`. Can you try with `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonNode`?

Comment: With JsonNode it works fine! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring (particularly Jackson) does not know how to deserialize `JSONObject`. You can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonNode` instead.